# How to move and build Asp.net project to other computer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I developed a website using VS2012, Asp.net MVC4 and entity framework in old computer.

and I copied the project to new computer, in VS2015 project folder, and try to run it. but there are many **warning sign** in reference.

I don't know what the warning sign means..

How can I solve that problem? so that I can build the project in new computer?

[image]

[image]

**[Edited]**

I did, 'Update-Package -Reinstall', and I found still some of reference are still with warning sign. and the package path was pointed to bin directory.

So I copied the bin directory then,

[image]

and,

[image]

How should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look on the old computer where are those references coming from. Whether they are added as NuGet packages or directly referenced from some `lib` folder which you forgot to copy. On the old computer click on the assembly reference and open the properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) which will show the physical path to the assembly. On the new computer you should replicate the same folder structure so that the assemblies can be resolved. Alternatively you may take a look at the corresponding `.csproj` file.

If they were added as NuGet packages, then you should restore them using the following command:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

This will look for a `packages.config` file in all projects in the current solution and download and install the NuGet packages listed there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could solved many reference problem, but still I couldn't solve it completed, could you help me a little more please? I updated the question for your review.

Comment: It's not enough to copy the assemblies to the `bin` folder. You also need to add a reference to them. Read the error message. It tells you what you need to do and which assembly you need to add as reference.